# Hidding Class using Javascript But Can't show Again

Tags: javascript, html

I want to create a filter using hide and showing a div class. When I usw JavaScript it can hide but can't show the div class again. Here's my code:

Html:

```html
<div class="filter">
  <div class="section text-center">
    <label class="u-check g-pl-0">
      <input class="g-hidden-xs-up g-pos-abs g-top-0 g-left-0" type="checkbox" name="Filter" value="20" checked onclick="filter()" />
      <span
        class="btn btn-md btn-block u-btn-outline-lightgray g-color-white--checked g-bg-primary--checked rounded-0">20MBPS</span>
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to hide and show this:

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 g-mb-30" id="20">
      <!-- Article -->
      <article
        class="h-100 g-pos-rel g-bg-gray-light-v5 g-transform-scale-1_05--hover g-transition-0_3 g-pt-30 g-px-30 g-pb-100"
      >
        <!-- Article Title -->
        <h4
          class="g-color-black g-font-size-16 g-font-weight-700"
          id="starter-price"
        >
          Starter
        </h4>
        <!-- End Article Title -->

        <hr class="g-brd-2 g-mt-15 g-mb-7" />

        <strong
          class="d-block g-color-black g-font-size-32 g-font-weight-700 g-mb-35"
        >
          <span class="d-inline-block g-font-size-16 g-valign-super">$</span>
          9.90
        </strong>
        <p class="g-mb-15">
          Facilisis at tortor vel, blandit tristique enim neque consectetur
        </p>

        <hr class="g-brd-2 g-mt-7 g-mb-30" />

        <ul class="list-unstyled g-mb-20">
          <li class="g-mb-10">
            <i class="fa fa-check-circle g-color-primary g-mr-5"></i>
            Support forum
          </li>
          <li class="g-mb-10">
            <i class="fa fa-check-circle g-color-primary g-mr-5"></i>
            Unlimited traffic
          </li>
          <li class="g-mb-10">
            <i class="fa fa-check-circle g-color-primary g-mr-5"></i>
            4GB of storage space
          </li>
        </ul>

        <footer class="g-pos-abs g-bottom-0 g-left-0 g-right-0 g-pa-30">
          <a
            class="btn w-100 u-btn-outline-primary g-brd-2 g-rounded-50 g-font-weight-700 g-pa-15-30"
            href="#!"
            >Order Now</a
          >
        </footer>
      </article>
      <!-- End Article -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And this for my javascript:

```js
function filter() {
  var fill = document.getElementsByClassName('g-hidden-xs-up g-pos-abs g-top-0 g-left-0')
  var value = fill[0].value;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName('col-md-4 g-mb-30');

  if (value.unchecked = '20') {

    document.getElementById('20').style.display = "none";
  }
  else if (value.checked = '20') {
    x.getElementById('20').style.display = "block";

  }
}
```

I'm new using Javascript. I will use it for filtering some menu only use hide and showing using `getElementById` and using method checked and uncheck. If checked that will show the menu, if unchecked will hide the menu.

Comment: Several issues: 1. `if(something = something else)` is an assignment statement. Equality requires `==` or `===`; 2.  `value` is a string. So `value.checked` and `value.unchecked` mean nothing. 3. Since you make an assignment to `value.unchecked`, the first if statement will always execute as the assignment statement works and is truthy.

Comment: .checked return boolean results, which is true/false only.